# RSKImageCropper can't configure for swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im want to use a small library called RSKImageCropper to crop the image
but when i want to call it nothing happens...even no crash

i've implemented everything like in a objective-c example

here is objective-c code from example:

```
#pragma mark - Action handling

- (void)onAddPhotoButtonTouch:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImage *photo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo"];
    RSKImageCropViewController *imageCropVC = [[RSKImageCropViewController alloc] initWithImage:photo cropMode:RSKImageCropModeCircle];
    imageCropVC.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:imageCropVC animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - RSKImageCropViewControllerDelegate

- (void)imageCropViewControllerDidCancelCrop:(RSKImageCropViewController *)controller
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)imageCropViewController:(RSKImageCropViewController *)controller didCropImage:(UIImage *)croppedImage usingCropRect:(CGRect)cropRect
{
    [self.addPhotoButton setImage:croppedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

here is my code :

```
class ViewController:  UIViewController, RSKImageCropViewControllerDelegate {


    @IBAction func addPhoto(sender: UIButton) {
        let image = UIImage(named: "picture")!
        let controller: RSKImageCropViewController = RSKImageCropViewController(image: image)
        controller.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
    func imageCropViewControllerDidCancelCrop(controller: RSKImageCropViewController) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    func imageCropViewController(controller: RSKImageCropViewController, didCropImage croppedImage: UIImage, usingCropRect cropRect: CGRect) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {


    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set  a breakpoint? Does the code get executed?

Comment: don't you forget to write swift code for this line?     [self.addPhotoButton setImage:croppedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: @fragilecat everything executed fine with breakpoints

Comment: @Krupanshu  i cant even get to the controller so, thats not important line

Comment: is your viewcontroller embedded in UINavigationController ?

Comment: @Krupanshu oh thank you a lot, write an answer so i can check it the right one !)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your **ViewController** must be embedded in **UINavigationController**. because as per your code, you viewcontroller is trying to push the RSKImageCropViewController object.

Comment: Hi, i have the exact same issue. what should i do if my ViewController is not  embedded in UINavigationController? can i still use it? i use a regular single view controler (in this View Controller i have a Scroll Vew and inside the Scroll View i have a View - if it is relevant). Thanks.

Comment: You can simply Embed your view controller in NavigationController it will work no matter what your View Contains. If you want to Push the controller then only you have to Embed that in Navigation. Otherwise try to Present that conrtoller.